# Simple fragmented tabhost in android

Tags: java, android

### I am trying to implement fragment-Tabhost in android

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Tab Variable
    ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2;

    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
    //Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
        //Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");

        // Set Tab Listeners
        Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        //Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
        //actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**FragmentTab2.java**

```
public class FragmentTab2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**FragmentTab3.java**

```
public class FragmentTab3 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab3, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

***At present just one tab with one activity is displaying***

**What i am trying to do** ::

- click on `tab1`(first time) - - - - > `FragmentTab2.java` must display
- Click on `tab1`(second time) - - - - > `FragmentTab3.java` must display
- click on `tab1`(third time)- - - - > `FragmentTab2.java` must display again

---

### This cycle must keep on repeating itself

What code changes should i need to make ?
 Any IDEAS ?

Comment: use a boolean value and set the fragment to the container based on the value

Comment: and why not have two tabs one for Fragment2 and one for Fragment3

Comment: @ Raghunandan ........ I want a flip flop nature of tabs ..... for simplicity i have showed just one tab ..... my end goal is three tabs navigating between 6 activities .... if i can do it for 1 tab with 2 activities others i can implement ! ..... Any help !

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html.for flipping check  this. But i am not sure what you are trying to do? how many tabs do you have?

Comment: @ Raghunandan ...........Can you give a solution using the boolean value to attain the result

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [TabListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html) and set to `Tab1.setTabListener()`.

When `onTabSelected()`, repeating replace fragment1 or fragment2.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, you still need to make some adjustments, but it will get you started.

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Notify, TabListener {

    ActionBar.Tab tab1;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    int count = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentTab2()).commit();
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    }
    //Callback
    @Override
    public void notifyTabListener() {
        count++;
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab" + count);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
    //Tablistener
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentTab2());
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(new FragmentTab2(), "Tab" + count);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Notify callback:

```
public interface Notify {
    public void notifyTabListener();
}
```

FragmentTab2:

```
public class FragmentTab2 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    Notify mCallback;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f2, container, false);
        LinearLayout  layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        layout.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallback = (MainActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCallback.notifyTabListener();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

f2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:text="Fragment2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```